# React hook useEffect causes initial render every time a component mounts

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new to React hooks. So, I wanted to implement componentWillReceiveProps with React hooks.
I used React.useEffect() like so:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.authLoginSuccess);  // initially called every time, the component renders
  }, [props.authLoginSuccess]);


return ( //JSX...)

onst mapStateToProps = (state: any): StateProps => {
  return {
    authLoginSuccess: selectAuthLoginSuccess(state) //used selector to select authLoginSuccess
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  // mapDispatchToProps
  { authLogin, toggleLoadingStatus } 
)(Auth);
```

The problem is, useEffect is called each time the component renders initially, which I don't want. I only want it to render, when "props.authLoginSuccess" changes.

Comment: What data structure is `props.authLoginSuccess`?

Comment: ...another wild guess: your component may be remounted by its parent(or alongside parent). you may check that by adding `useEffect(() => { console.log('mounted!'); return () => console.log('unmounted');}, [])`

Comment: @go_diego, props.authLoginSuccess is a boolean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want the effect to not run on initial render, you can do that by making use of `useRef`

```
const initialRender = useRef(true);
React.useEffect(() => {
    if(initialRender.current) {
        initialRender.current = false;
    } else {
        console.log(props.authLoginSuccess);  // initially called every time, the component renders
    }
  }, [props.authLoginSuccess]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in an `if` condition like this:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (props.authLoginSuccess) {
    console.log(props.authLoginSuccess);
  }
}, [props.authLoginSuccess]);
```

Note that the effect will still run though - both initially and every time `props.authLoginSuccess` changes (which is okay!).

The `if` block will prevent running `console.log(props.authLoginSuccess)` when `props.authLoginSuccess` is falsy. So if you don't want it running initially i.e. when component *mounts*, just make sure that `props.authLoginSuccess` is `false` initially.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another state that would monitor whether or not the component has been mounted.

```
const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (isMounted) {
    console.log(props.authLoginSuccess);
  } else {
    setIsMounted(true);
  }
}, [props.authLoginSuccess]);
```

That way, it will only execute when the component has been mounted.

Comment: This is a workaround and I have tried that too, does not help with my case.