# componentWillReceiveProps to React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to change class based component to functional component and i have

```
const initialState={

     displayName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
        error: "",
    }


componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps,nextContext){
const userError=nextProps;
if(userError){
this.setState({error:userError.message});
}
}
```

And i make selector

```
export const selectUserError = createSelector(
  [selectUser],
  (user) => user.error
);





 {this.state.error ? (
        <SweetAlert
          show={this.state.error}
          type="warning"
          title="Something went wrong"
          text={this.props.userError}
          onConfirm={() => this.setState({ error: "" })}
        />
      ) : null}
```

and i pass into mapState to props.
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hook useEffect causes initial render every time a component mounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169886/react-hook-useeffect-causes-initial-render-every-time-a-component-mounts)

Comment: not really. Im little bit stuck with this

Comment: What's the reason that you're copying a value from props into state (in the class version)?

Comment: Because i want to display message to the UI with sweetalert, for example the email taken etc.

Comment: Why can you not do that directly with the prop?

Comment: Show your error message from `props` directly rather than setting it to `state` first.

Comment: You can directly use the error from props, don't need to copy it into state

Comment: Can you please write example with my code?

Comment: Well, just whatever code is currently using `this.state.error`, it would refer to `this.props.message` instead. So if you have somewhere where you call, say, `swal(this.state.error)`, it would become `swal(this.props.message)`.

Comment: It's okay, i kinda understand it, but i don't know how to change my code into hooks?

Comment: Ok, what code do you need to change into hooks? You've shown us a componentWillReceiveProps, and it seems we've settled on that not being needed at all. Other than that you've shown us an initialState object and a selector, neither of which will change when using hooks.

Comment: Im edited my comment, i change initialState into useState and i want to change componentwillReceiveProps

Comment: Delete the componentWillRecieveProps. Delete state.error. Use props.message. Sorry if i'm being abrupt, i just don't have much to work with to give you an answer.

Comment: Can you post how, sweetAlert uses the error from your state with your current code

Comment: Yes im edited..

Comment: @NicholasTower no problem, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the props in state, you can simply use the data from props

```
const {userError} = this.props;
...
 {userError && userError.message ? (
        <SweetAlert
          show={!!userError.message}
          type="warning"
          title="Something went wrong"
          text={userError.message}
          onConfirm={() => this.props.dispatch({ type: 'RESET_ERROR', error: "" })} // Dispatch and action here that updates state in store
        />
      ) : null}
```

Comment: but the componentWillreceiveProps is still there :/ that's what i want to change

Comment: don't change it, you just remove it. There is no need to copy props to state specially if it is directly derivable from props

Comment: Assuming your mapStateToProps is like `const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
   return {
      userError: selectUserError(state, props)
  }
}`, the above code would work. Please see that you are using props and not state anywhere in sweetalert

Comment: this.props.dispatch is not a function, it's working, but i get this back, when i click the OK in the sweetalert window

Comment: Do you know how to dispatch an action and update the user.error state in redux? If so follow that to replace the onConfirm action. The dispatch was a dummy in the above post to inform that a redux action needs to be dispatched

Comment: wait, this.props.userError.message above the sweetalert is the problem.
No i want the simpliest solution for this
this is my mapStateToProps : const mapStateToProps = () => ({
  userError: selectUserError,
});

Comment: ohh dear. You must really read redux. Above code is a simplest solution, you just need to implement it

Comment: Sorry dude. I know im not the best, i try to learn this, im very beginner to this.
i copy your code and this is what i get back Cannot read property 'message' of null

Comment: You have mapStateToProps, but mapDispatchToProps is actually used to dispatch action. If you don't provide mapDispatchToProps, its passes a dispatch function as a prop. You can use it to dispatch and action like I showed above. Now you need to listen to that action in redux store and update the user state to empty the error

Comment: Updated my post with a null case handling

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @shubham-khatri help, i solved the problem.
I make RESET_ERROR type in my user.types, after that i make action reseterror. 
Dispatched in my sign up component and after that i can use in onConfirm method.
It works fine.